# How to merge 3 columns and 10 rows in one single column as json data

Tags: sql-server

i have 10 rows and 3 columns,

out of 3 columns, 2 columns have data in `JSON` format

I am trying to merge the data of all rows in one single column which has the json data and that is valid,

like if row 1 has a `json`, it should join the json and the column name and then next row and so on

Have been able to do so my data is repeated like this

```
[   {
      "role":"poweruser",
      "account":"active",
      "Name" : "Rose"   
   
},
   {
      "role":"Admin",
      "account":"inactive",
      "Name" : "Rose" 
   
}]
```

output i am trying is like this

```
[{
    "name":"Rose" {
          "role":"poweruser",
          "account":"active"   
          },
          {
          "role":"Admin",
          "account":"inactive"
          }
    }]
```

and my table structure is like this

```
select role,account,(another case statement) as name 
from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

but i want that the JSON should not repeat the name, one name and other two as nested output
Literally have no clue what i should be doing, suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Microsof SQL Server has some integrated support for handling JSON, you can check out some of the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-for-clause-transact-sql#for-json).

Working with the "table structure" query and the little example data you provided I get this:

```
-- create sample data
declare @user table
(
    userid int,
    username nvarchar(20)
);

insert into @user (userid, username) values
(1, 'Rose');


declare @userrole table
(
    userid int,
    rolename nvarchar(20),
    rolestatus nvarchar(20)
);

insert into @userrole (userid, rolename, rolestatus) values
(1, 'poweruser', 'active'),
(1, 'admin', 'inactive');
```

A very basic query where SQL Server does all the work:

```
select  u.username as 'Name',
        roles.rolename as 'Role',
        roles.rolestatus as 'Account'
from @user u
join @userrole Roles
    on Roles.userid = u.userid
for json auto; -- specify that we want JSON output with AUTOmatic structure
```

This gives:

```
[{"Name":"Rose","roles":[{"Role":"poweruser","Account":"active"},{"Role":"admin","Account":"inactive"}]}]
```

Which can be formatted as:

```
[
    {
        "Name":"Rose",
        "Roles":
        [
            {
                "Role":"poweruser",
                "Account":"active"
            },
            {
                "Role":"admin",
                "Account":"inactive"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Please expand your question (with more example data) if this is not what you are after.